# Wire-up links to show lists on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation menu made from nested lists.  On lower screen widths (<800px) I want to simply show all list items/hyperlinks.

However, for larger widths, I want to only show the child-lists when the respective hyperlink is hovered over.  My approach (and there may be a better way which I am eager to hear about!) is:

- Check the screen width
- If >800px then hide the nested lists
- Wire up the links to show their respective list (adjacent sibling) when hovered over

I am struggling with the final step and would appreciate some guidance please.  One consideration is that if JS is disabled, then the lists should all appear as per lower screen widths.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetupNavMenus();
});

/* 
If the screen width is greater than 800px, hide the child lists and wire-up the 
hyperlinks to show them on hover
*/
function SetupNavMenus() {
    if (screen.width > 800) {
        HideSubMenus();
        WireUpExpandableLinks();
    }
}

function HideSubMenus() {
    $("#menus ul ul").hide();
}

function WireUpExpandableLinks() {
    $("#menus ul a").each(function() {
        // show the respective list on link:hover
    });
}

function ShowSubMenu(lnk) {
    $(lnk).next('ul').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

[A JsFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vj8VA/2/)

Comment: Just create 2 seperate menus in html, hide the widescreen one with display:none; in css. In js if screen>800 show widescreen and hide normal one

Comment: Sorry but that is something I really am keen to avoid. More code and more maintenance!

Comment: Ok, i wrote an answer that does not involve code duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a css class for the big menu, and add it with your js - based on your fiddle:

```
//css
.big ul ul {display:none;}
.big ul li:hover ul {display:block;}


<div id="menus">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="1.htm">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="2.htm">Link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="3.htm">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="4.htm">Link 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li>
            <a href="5.htm">Link 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="6.htm">Link 6</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="7.htm">Link 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    SetupNavMenus();
});


function SetupNavMenus() {
    if (screen.width > 800) {
        $('#menus').addClass('big');
    }
}
```

EDIT as per your comment, you can write your js like this:

```
function SetupNavMenus() {
    if (screen.width > 800) {
        HideSubMenus();
        WireUpExpandableLinks();
    }
}

function HideSubMenus() {
    $("#menus ul ul").hide();
}

function WireUpExpandableLinks() {
    //create event listener for mouseenter (as hover fires twice)
    $("#menus ul a").mouseenter( function() {
        ShowSubMenu(this);
    });
}

function ShowSubMenu(lnk) {
    //hide any open menues, show correct one. Will stay open until another is hovered
    $('#menus ul ul').hide();
    $(lnk).next('ul').show('fast');
}
```

Comment: Elegant and simple, but it presents some issues.  First, I lose the ability to use JQuery animation to show the lists (`.show(200)`).  Second, I don't want the child lists to be hidden as the mouse moves out from the link, but instead to remain visible.

Comment: Superb.  Exactly what I was after.  Thank you very much